# I want to show an alert when users close popup

Tags: javascript, php

I want to show a popup (Google, Twitter etc) and when users close that dialog, I want to show an alert "bye", but that alert does not appear:

```
<script>
var openDialog = function(uri, name, options, closeCallback) {
var win = window.open(uri, name, options);
var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    try {
        if (win == null || win.closed) {
            window.clearInterval(interval);
            closeCallback(win);
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
}, 1000);
return win;
};
var test = function() {
alert("bye");
};

openDialog("//google.com", "popup", "scrollbars=no", "test");
</script>
```

Comment: "test" should be test on the openDialog(..test) line

Comment: Actually, it was first time for me to use Stackoverflow. I received so many benefits from you guys. Thank you again.

Comment: Anytime, glad we helped, can i get the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Change this code

```
openDialog("//google.com", "popup", "scrollbars=no", "test");
```

with that:

```
openDialog("//google.com", "popup", "scrollbars=no", test);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3on19uak/

Comment: You can accept this answer, if you think it is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
 openDialog("//google.com", "popup", "scrollbars=no", "test");
```

**Should read:**

```
 openDialog("//google.com", "popup", "scrollbars=no", test);
```

if you wanted you could also do:

```
 openDialog("//google.com", "popup", "scrollbars=no", function(e){
    alert("bye");
 });
```